# I have a huge problem with Javascript decimal rounding

Tags: javascript, precision

After doing a lot of looking around, I don't have to describe the precision problem that is apparent in the coding community. However, most solutions rely on converting the number to a string. In my case, that is not an option since I am using an API which requires the passed in number to be well.. a number. And every time I get the imperfect precision the API shoots out an error breaking my application's functionality. Simply catching the error is not really a solution, since I still have to submit the value and the value will not be changing. Here's what I am currently using and it seems to work for the most part, but every once in a while I'm not so lucky, if anyone has an idea of how to work around this all comments will be appreciated!

```
let rounded = Math.round((n + Number.EPSILON) * Math.round(Math.pow(10, precision))) / Math.round(Math.pow(10, precision))
let fixed = rounded.toFixed(precision)
return Number(fixed)
```

Side note, both rounded and fixed can cause the same issue, I've tried it both ways, and desired precision is from 2 to 8 depends on the circumstance, I've also tried it with and without EPSILON, I've tried truncating, rounding, nothing seems to work, and I need a number at the end not a string...

Comment: Hi, please add a couple of examples of how exactly it doesn't work.

Comment: Please provide examples of inputs that cause these errors and inputs that do not. You can use Stack Snippets (icon looks like `<>` in the editor toolbar) to provide running code, which will help people understand the issue.

Comment: A number can't have a fixed precision, e.g. 0.1 can't be stored as binary in memory. What API expects a number with fixed precision?

Comment: @ThomasSablik Binance.US, I just found out they accept strings even though their documentation strictly states a number -.- time to rework my whole app, as for the rest of you if you need examples you're not qualified to answer this question

Answer (score 0):

## `decimal.js`

Use `decimal.js` for mathematically precise computations. Similar solutions are available.
Your issues are a known fact about using floating point numbers in programming in general.

You can find more help and tutorials about decimal.js online. Have a look:
https://github.com/MikeMcl/decimal.js/